# Merging list items based on adjacency of first element of list items

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, tuples

I've a list like :

```
temp_list = [(18, [2773]), (57, [87]), (98, [34]), (135, [5]), (140, [56]), (164, [2151]), (165, [2194, 2101, 2049]), (166, [2298, 2244, 2004]), (167, [2343]), (236, [2752]), (245, [636]), (250, [2290, 2241, 2194, 2146, 2098, 2050, 2001]), (251, [2337, 1952]), (252, [1905, 1857]), (253, [1809]), (254, [1760, 1713, 1661]), (255, [1614]), (256, [1717, 1564, 1522]), (284, [2773]), (303, [2744]), (339, [1842]), (340, [560]), (341, [945]), (342, [1026, 975, 875, 854, 833, 783]), (343, [1093]), (344, [1601, 1477, 1440, 1384, 1362, 1327, 1298, 1237, 1203, 1181, 1130]), (413, [972, 924, 880, 787]), (414, [1067, 1019, 834]), (415, [1299, 1160, 1114]), (416, [1253, 1207]), (487, [555, 491]), (488, [459]), (489, [522]), (490, [2130, 2092, 1791, 1752, 1589]), (491, [2243, 2206, 2168, 2053, 1870, 1831, 1713, 1635, 1513, 1476]), (492, [2358, 2321, 2283, 1673, 1551]), (569, [2046, 1981, 1956]), (570, [2137, 2111, 2073, 2019, 1922]), (619, [535]), (621, [684]), (623, [979]), (624, [1110, 613]), (625, [2060]), (626, [1774]), (690, [1824, 1771, 1721]), (691, [1926, 1902, 1849, 1798, 1746, 1694]), (700, [2743]), (893, [421]), (894, [650, 602, 556, 510, 466]), (895, [746, 697]), (896, [1160]), (898, [524, 479, 435]), (899, [760, 717, 665, 615, 568]), (925, [1273]), (932, [1087]), (936, [1127]), (964, [700, 604, 558]), (965, [2775, 747, 649]), (1018, [2785]), (1039, [426])]
```

I want to check consecutively whether the first items in the tuple items of the list are adjacent by margin of 2 and if adjacent then merge the second item of the tuple (which is a list) and add all of them to another list, and assign to the key .

To simplify, we check from first item of the tuple as `18` in the list and check the immediate next `57`, as `(18+2 >= 57)` is `False`, we assign 18 as the key and [2773] as the value in another dictionary.

Now starting from the tuple whose first item is `164`, next tuple has first item `165` which fulfills `(164+2>=165)`, we continue to the next tuple whose firsty item is `166` which also fulfills adjacency condition, same for the next tuple with first item `167` but the next tuple with first item `236` doesn't fullfill adjacency condition as `(167+2 >= 236) == False`. So we add all second items of tuples from `[2151]` to `[2343]` in a new list and assign to the key with lowest value `164`.

I have tried this code :

```
# First Loop Part
a = []
b = []
for i in temp_list[:-1]:
    if temp_list[temp_list.index(i)+1][0] - i[0] >= 2:
        a.append(i[0])
        b.append(temp_list[temp_list.index(i)+1][0])
c = {}
# Second Loop Part
for i in range(len(a)-1):
    k = []
    for l in temp_list:
        if l[0] == a[i]:
            ts = temp_list.index(l)
    for l in temp_list:
        if l[0] == a[i+1]:
            te = temp_list.index(l)
    for j in temp_list[ts : te]:
        k.append(j[1])
    k = [item for sublist in k for item in sublist]
    c[a[i]] = k
```

I'm having

```
a = [18, 57, 98, 135, 140, 167, 236, 245, 256, 284, 303, 344, 416, 492, 570, 619, 621, 626, 691, 700, 896, 899, 925, 932, 936, 965, 1018]
```

and

```
b = [57, 98, 135, 140, 164, 236, 245, 250, 284, 303, 339, 413, 487, 569, 619, 621, 623, 690, 700, 893, 898, 925, 932, 936, 964, 1018, 1039]
```

None of these two lists are right as required. The list according to the logic should be :

```
[18, 57, 98, 135, 140, 164, 236, 245, 250, 284, 303, 339, 413, 487, 569, 619, 690, 700, 893, 925, 932, 936, 964, 1018, 1039]
```

However the work of assigning values to the keys in the dictionary part is done right. I'm getting

```
c = {18: [2773], 57: [87], 98: [34], 135: [5], 140: [56, 2151, 2194, 2101, 2049, 2298, 2244, 2004], 167: [2343], 236: [2752], 245: [636, 2290, 2241, 2194, 2146, 2098, 2050, 2001, 2337, 1952, 1905, 1857, 1809, 1760, 1713, 1661, 1614], 256: [1717, 1564, 1522], 284: [2773], 303: [2744, 1842, 560, 945, 1026, 975, 875, 854, 833, 783, 1093], 344: [1601, 1477, 1440, 1384, 1362, 1327, 1298, 1237, 1203, 1181, 1130, 972, 924, 880, 787, 1067, 1019, 834, 1299, 1160, 1114], 416: [1253, 1207, 555, 491, 459, 522, 2130, 2092, 1791, 1752, 1589, 2243, 2206, 2168, 2053, 1870, 1831, 1713, 1635, 1513, 1476], 492: [2358, 2321, 2283, 1673, 1551, 2046, 1981, 1956], 570: [2137, 2111, 2073, 2019, 1922], 619: [535], 621: [684, 979, 1110, 613, 2060], 626: [1774, 1824, 1771, 1721], 691: [1926, 1902, 1849, 1798, 1746, 1694], 700: [2743, 421, 650, 602, 556, 510, 466, 746, 697], 896: [1160, 524, 479, 435], 899: [760, 717, 665, 615, 568], 925: [1273], 932: [1087], 936: [1127, 700, 604, 558], 965: [2775, 747, 649]}
```

What would be right way to implement the adjacency list items logic? Any help with the first loop part would be of great help as the second loop part would be rightly working if we get the first list (a or b) right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pair the adjacent tuples by zipping the list with itself with an offset of 1, append the tuple to a temporary list `c` if it is not adjacent to the last tuple, or extend the list in the last tuple if adjacent, and instantiate a dict with the resulting list of tuples:

```
c = []
for (a, _), (b, l) in zip([(None, [])] + temp_list, temp_list):
    if a is None or b - a >= 2:
        c.append((b, l))
    else:
        c[-1][1].extend(l)
```

so that `dict(c)` becomes:

```
{18: [2773], 57: [87], 98: [34], 135: [5], 140: [56], 164: [2151, 2194, 2101, 2049, 2298, 2244, 2004, 2343], 236: [2752], 245: [636], 250: [2290, 2241, 2194, 2146, 2098, 2050, 2001, 2337, 1952, 1905, 1857, 1809, 1760, 1713, 1661, 1614, 1717, 1564, 1522], 284: [2773], 303: [2744], 339: [1842, 560, 945, 1026, 975, 875, 854, 833, 783, 1093, 1601, 1477, 1440, 1384, 1362, 1327, 1298, 1237, 1203, 1181, 1130], 413: [972, 924, 880, 787, 1067, 1019, 834, 1299, 1160, 1114, 1253, 1207], 487: [555, 491, 459, 522, 2130, 2092, 1791, 1752, 1589, 2243, 2206, 2168, 2053, 1870, 1831, 1713, 1635, 1513, 1476, 2358, 2321, 2283, 1673, 1551], 569: [2046, 1981, 1956, 2137, 2111, 2073, 2019, 1922], 619: [535], 621: [684], 623: [979, 1110, 613, 2060, 1774], 690: [1824, 1771, 1721, 1926, 1902, 1849, 1798, 1746, 1694], 700: [2743], 893: [421, 650, 602, 556, 510, 466, 746, 697, 1160], 898: [524, 479, 435, 760, 717, 665, 615, 568], 925: [1273], 932: [1087], 936: [1127], 964: [700, 604, 558, 2775, 747, 649], 1018: [2785], 1039: [426]}
```